# Query TeXLive paths

Tags: texlive

How can I query for TeXLive installation paths? (**Edit:** Personally I only need solution for Linux/bash.)

I tried to google it, hoped `tlmgr` documentation might help but was unable to find any useful info.

**Rationale:** I've written some [macros for adding notes to presentations](https://bitbucket.org/Marcel-S/beamerendnotes) for my friend who often uses Beamer and I'd like to add some simple installation script that would just query TeXLive paths, add those macros to the `texmf-local` directory and run `texhash`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

Reason: this even works on Windows and doesn't require quoting or `$`.

Example, on my machine (`>` stands for the prompt, user name masked):

```
> kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFMAIN;kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL;kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
/Users/<myname>/Library/texmf
```

Comment: Both fast (which is not really a concern here, but still…) and not requiring any further parsing.

Answer (score 5):

there are a range of kpse... utilities eg

```
kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'
```

will give the input path, for me:

```
.:{{}/home/davidc/.texlive2017/texmf-config,/home/davidc/.texlive2017/texmf-var,
/home/davidc/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//
```

or

```
kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'
```

which returns

```
/home/davidc/texmf
```

Comment: Thank you David, yours runs faster (tlmgr takes its time) but needs probably more parsing.

Comment: @MarcelS. You should thank by up-voting and awarding a green tick to the best answer!

Comment: @Andrew Absolutely, however I wanted to add some info as well.

Comment: Hi @MarcelS. I'm not sure what you mean by "as well" because there is only one up-vote and it's not yours! :)

Answer (score 3):

Found it! :-)

```
tlmgr conf | grep TEXMFLOCAL
```